# Добавление в QListWidget пользовательского QWidget

Tags: c++, qt

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите почему после выполнения данного кода listMessages отстает пустой

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    QListWidgetItem *item_mess = new QListWidgetItem();
    QString text = "Text Message";
    QString avatar = "avatars/avatar.png";

    QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    QTextEdit *textEdit = new QTextEdit( text );
    QLabel *label = new QLabel();

    QPixmap pix( avatar );
    label->setPixmap( pix );

    layout->addWidget( label );
    layout->addWidget( textEdit );

    widget->setLayout( layout );

    ui->listMessages->addItem( item_mess );
    ui->listMessages->setItemWidget( item_mess, widget );
}
```

P.S. Ошибок компиляции и рантайм нет. Просто после того, как этот код будет выполнен ( я проверял, что он исполняется ) listMessages остается пустой.

Comment: Оффтоп конечно, но вы задачу слишком сложно решаете. Все что вам нужно уже есть в `QListWidgetItem`  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html

Answer (score 3):

Установите для `widget` минимальную высоту и увидите свой кастомный делегат. Например, так:

```
widget->setMinimumHeight(40);
```

Менеджеры размещения (layouts) по умолчанию, если не ошибаюсь, устанавливают отступ, равный 8 пикселям. Поэтому, чтобы виджет "лёг" ровнее, установите отступ в нулевое значение:

```
layout->setMargin(0);
```

А если по всем правилам, то, как написано в справке, в случае необходимости использования комплексных делегатов, лучше воспользоваться `QListView` и наследованием от `QStyledItemDelegate`.